# PubSub replacement..?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, rss

Looks like all the **PubSub framework** classes have been deprecated in OS X v10.9:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/PubSub/Reference/PSFeed_reference/translated_content/PSFeed.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011470
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/PubSub/Reference/PSClient_reference/translated_content/PSClient.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011464
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/PubSub/Reference/PSEntry_reference/translated_content/PSEntry.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011469
- ...

Except there's no hint in the docs what to use instead.
Does Apple have a successor for PubSub..?

Answer (score 1):

There is no replacement for PubSub in OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Any communication whatsoever from Apple regarding RSS support..?

Comment: Not beyond the deprecation of PubSub and removal of RSS features from several of their applications, no.